# Could not load hsdis-amd64.dylib; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled

Tags: java

I wrote simple java program and I am getting A fatal error with Could not load hsdis-amd64.dylib; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled. I tried to read several block but did not find solution. Can anyone please help me?
Here is complete error message

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGFPE (0x8) at pc=0x0000000118e9ea48, pid=4481, tid=7683

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (11.0.9+7) (build 11.0.9+7-LTS)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (11.0.9+7-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)
Problematic frame:
j  com.sun.tools.javac.comp.ConstFold.fold2(ILcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type;Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type;)Lcom/sun/tools/javac/code/Type;+877 jdk.compiler@11.0.9
 No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

Compiled method (c1)     884  193       3       java.lang.System::getSecurityManager (4 bytes)
 total in heap  [0x0000000119455010,0x0000000119455338] = 808
 relocation     [0x0000000119455178,0x00000001194551a0] = 40
 main code      [0x00000001194551a0,0x0000000119455260] = 192
 stub code      [0x0000000119455260,0x00000001194552f0] = 144
 metadata       [0x00000001194552f0,0x00000001194552f8] = 8
 scopes data    [0x00000001194552f8,0x0000000119455300] = 8
 scopes pcs     [0x0000000119455300,0x0000000119455330] = 48
 dependencies   [0x0000000119455330,0x0000000119455338] = 8

Could not load hsdis-amd64.dylib; library not loadable; PrintAssembly is disabled
```

Comment: you can check https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-support/issues/211 and opening a issue in github may help more.

Comment: That error - _"Could not load hsdis-amd64.dylib"_ - is referencing a library file under the `lib` directory in the JDK install. Can't tell why from your post, but it could be the file is actually missing, or maybe it's present but with insufficient permissions (is it world-readable?).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with JDK1.8.0_202

I didn't find an appropriate closed task at [JDK Bug system](https://bugs.openjdk.org/projects/JDK/issues/JDK-8305968?filter=allopenissues), but for me helped a switch to JDK 17.0.2

> The PrintAssembly HotSpot option is a diagnostic flag for the JVM that allows us to capture the generated assembly instructions of the JIT compiler. This requires the latest OpenJDK release or a new version of HotSpot, update 14 or above.

[Source](https://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency/)